# Excel interprets multiple columns from Notepad data as one column

Tags: excel, import, notepad

I have some data in notepad that look like this:

[image]

All separated nicely. i try to export it to excel by going to:

Data -> From Text/CSV but Excel does this:

[image]

Obviously I want 11 columns and not 1. I have never imported data from notepad so maybe I am doing something wrong. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Select all, click text to columns, select Delimiters → Space → Finish.

Answer (score 1):

You should use data > text to columns and use tab as a delimiter on the selection of the first column. The data is a tsv (tab seperated values) and not a comma seperated values (csv).

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you have to select `--Fixed Width--` when importing such a file (middle dropdown):

[image]

But you have to insert the different lengths at which each column ends. I find that doing that is quite a pain to use since one needs to count the characters (it's a bit easier in text editors which tell you the cursor position, but it's still quite a lot of manual work, and it was not like this in earlier versions, which is sad)...

So I'd really import it as you did, then use the text to columns feature:

[image]

Next, adjust the column separators as you need:

[image]

Next, assign data types as required (you can select multiple columns by holding down the shift key):

[image]

Click on finish, and that should be it!

[image]